# Incorrect colors when decoding JPEG using image.Decode and writing to PDF?

Tags: image, go, pdf, pdf-generation, jpeg

I'm trying to create a PDF by decoding image files (in PNG, JPG, GIF, and BMP format) using the `image.Decode()` method to get the `image.Image`. Then, I write the pixel data into a PDF stream, which is later compressed. The problem I'm encountering is that when I decode a JPEG, the colors are incorrect in the resulting PDF. All other image formats are working as expected. I've attached a screenshot of the issue.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3Hc8.png

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? Is there a specific way that JPEGs need to be handled differently when using `image.Decode()`? Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Code:

```golang
var iData image.Image
iFile, err := os.Open(path)
if err != nil {
  [...]
} else {
  iData, _, err = image.Decode(iFile)
}
```

```golang
[...]
x.Dictionary.Set("ColorSpace", "/DeviceRGB")
x.Dictionary.Set("BitsPerComponent", 8)
for j := 0; j < iData.Bounds().Dy()/pixelMul; j++ {
    for k := 0; k < iData.Bounds().Dx()/pixelMul; k++ {
        r, g, b, _ := iData.At(k*pixelMul, j*pixelMul).RGBA()
        x.Write([]byte{byte(r), byte(g), byte(b)})
    }
}
[...]
```

The resulting image in the pdf looks the same when using the `jpeg.Decode` directly.

I exptect the image in the resulting pdf to look just like the original png with possibly a bit of degredation.

Original PNG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNkGq.png

Converted JPG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ69y.jpg

Other JPEGs also have the same issue, e.g. the first test JPEG from w3c https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Test/xhtml-print/20050519/tests/A_2_1-BF-01.htm

Comment: What happens if you open the JPEG in an image viewer? Does it look correct, or also wrong like in the output PDF?

Comment: Judging from the image, it looks to me you used too low JPEG quality when generating the JPEG, that's why colors are off (and other artifacts), so the issue is not with Go decoding it but the JPEG generation process.

Comment: The image looks just fine in every image viewer I've tried @icza

Comment: Can you share the JPEG file?

Comment: Added links to the question. The JPEG is a bit lower quality due to the upload, but the same problem persists if I use the uploaded image

Comment: You would need to share the original JPEG file, not host the image on a site which likely reencodes it.

Comment: But the exact same problem occurs when downloading the image from the link and using that. So no need to upload the original JPEG as the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Color.RGBA()`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#Color) returns the alpha-premultiplied color components in the range of `0..0xffff`.

Converting such a value to `byte` like `byte(r)` will keep its lowest 8 bits which will seemingly be just random compared to the original value. You need an 8-bit color component, do not convert it to `byte` but use the higher 8 bits, which means shift right by 8 (or divide by 256):

```
x.Write([]byte{byte(r>>8), byte(g>>8), byte(b>>8)})
```

Explanation why it still worked for PNG and GIF, but not for JPEG:

Decoding PNG and GIF images likely uses an image model that uses the [`color.RGBA`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#RGBA) color model, which stores components using 8-bit values. But its `RGBA.RGBA()` method converts these values to 16-bit values by duplicating the original 8-bit values:

```
func (c RGBA) RGBA() (r, g, b, a uint32) {
    r = uint32(c.R)
    r |= r << 8
    g = uint32(c.G)
    g |= g << 8
    b = uint32(c.B)
    b |= b << 8
    a = uint32(c.A)
    a |= a << 8
    return
}
```

Which means if you take the lower 8 bits, you get the same original value just as if you take the 8 higher bits. Decoding JPEG images will likely use the [`color.YCbCr`](https://pkg.go.dev/image/color#YCbCr) color type which does not reproduce this "implementation behavior".

Do not depend on this. When you need an 8-bit component from a 16-bit component, always use the higher 8 bits.